# Mac Bootable USB not showing in boot menu

Tags: linux, usb, macintosh

So the other day I created a MultiBoot USB using SARDU (It was the only one that worked with my 4TB hard drive).  I had done this on my Windows 7 and thought, "Hmmmmmm, you know what would this really smoothly problem free?  Mac!"  I checked System Preferences and the Option boot menu, however nothing appeared.  I have reset my PRAM but it didn't seem to help.  I might be doing something stupid.  Anyways, I kind of want to know if anyone can fix this.  Thanks.